# Introducing URL encoding / obfuscation in testcafe-hammerhead url-rewrite proxy

Tags: testcafe

First of all thanks for the amazing work behind `testcafe-hammerhead`, I'm creating a question here because I feel like this might not belong on the github issues tracker, maybe I could make an argument for it as a feature request but it might be a bit out of scope since our feature request is more privacy focused rather than testing.

I'm trying to introduce url encoding / obfuscation to the `destUrl` in `testcafe-hammerhead` and am looking for some general feedback or advice from people familiar with the `testcafe-hammerhead` codebase in specific.

Our current approach uses a few lightweight hooks to the following:

#### Server side

- `RequestPipelineContext.prototype.dispatch`: This is where I decode the incoming url, making sure to decode `this.req.headers[BUILTIN_HEADERS.referer]` as well if needed.
- `RequestPipelineContext.prototype.toProxyUrl`: This is where I encode the `destUrl` part of the proxy url.
- `Proxy.prototype._onTaskScriptRequest`: This is where I decode the `task.js` referer header.
- `DomProcessor.prototype._processUrlAttrs`: I'm hooking this to make sure I avoid encoding `pattern.urlAttr?.toLowerCase() === 'action'` urls.

#### Client side

- `getProxyUrl`: This is where I encode the `destUrl` part of the url.
- `parseProxyUrl`: This is where I decode the `destUrl` part of the url.

Client side we use a build step to make minor modifications to `hammerhead.js` to expose the correct hooks that a second custom script will use before `task.js` is loaded.

The hooks function well overall, however, issues arise with complex JavaScript and iframes, particularly when manipulating window hashes or using regex matches on the "current" `window.location`, causing some websites to break.

---

I'm wondering if there's maybe a better target client side to implement the encoding to avoid the complications that we're facing.

I've taken a lot of inspiration from the `rammerhead` [web proxy project](https://github.com/binary-person/rammerhead) with the above hooks, but due to their custom standalone session handling it's not been as easy as just porting over the code. We intend to run our solution as close to stock hammerhead as possible and would like to stick with the default way of handling sessions that hammerhead provides.

Client side I'm wondering if this can be solved directly from a getter / setter hook, that I suspect hammerhead might already be using, if anyone has a comment on that or can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.